# Use JQuery to select a dropdown option and fire the OnChange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that loads with a dropdown in it with a select dropdown list with an `id = "accounts"`. When the page loads it is already on the Account Orange page. I would like to use JQuery to find the select id element and then force it click on the 3 option which should be index 2.

```
<select id="accounts" onChange="changeAccount(this.form,this[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    <OPTION value="">Select One...</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="111">Account Red</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="222">Account Yellow</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="333">Account Blue</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="444" selected>Account Orange</OPTION>
</select>
```

Something like this works:

```
jQuery('#accounts>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
```

Currently when the page loads it does select the correct option despite the "selected" tag but it does not fire it to the OnChange function to select "Account Yellow" and then it would reload the page. That's what I would like it to do.

Comment: `jQuery('#accounts>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);`

Comment: Thanks. That answered the first part. Updated my original question

Comment: `jQuery('#accounts).trigger('change')`

Comment: I ended using this `jQuery('#accounts>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true).change();`

Answer (score 0):

First, it's better to set the value of the `SELECT` by value instead of index. Because you might want to add extra `OPTION`'s later (in your source code or dynamically) and then your index count is off.

Second, I find it better practice to change the value of the `SELECT`, instead of changing HTML attributes/properties which make it selected (e.g. not setting/changing the `selected` property of the `OPTION`, but changing the value of the `SELECT`). Otherwise, you might end up with more than one `selected` `OPTION`'s which might work, but is not very clean coding.

Third, the suggested `>option:eq(2)` selector might not work if you're using `OPTGROUP`'s, because then the `OPTION` is not a direct descendant of `SELECT`.

So, my suggestion is to use:
`jQuery('#accounts').val('222').change();`

It selects the right `SELECT` field, then sets the value to `333` and then fires the `onchange` event (you need to do that manually in this case).

Comment: OP wants to play with the index, not with the value!

Comment: True, but it's safer to set it by `value` as you might add `option`'s later, or dynamically, and then your count/index is off

Comment: Both of you are correct. But for this situation, the option values will never change so index values work perfectly

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
jQuery('#accounts>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true).closest('select').trigger('change');
```

Comment: I reckon `trigger` should be applied to `select` not `option` !

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#accounts>option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true).promise().then(function(){
     changeAccount(this.form,this[this.selectedIndex].value)
});
```